# PHP & mySQL obtaining last insert ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to this php/mysql deal and I'm having a hard time figuring out this situation particularily.

I have two tables, one of them is "dog" table and the other one is the "date" table. In order to insert a record in the "dog" table I MUST first insert a date in the "table" date and get the autoincrement id from that date.

Problem is that I've tried reading several posts on how to get the last insert id from a table you just inserted a record on and I can't seem to make it work.

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO FECHAS (fecha) VALUES (NOW())";
mysql_query($sql1);
echo $sql1;

$sql3="SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
mysql_query($sql3);
echo $sql3;



  $sql2="INSERT INTO PERRO (nombre_perro,FECHAS_id_fecha) VALUES ('$nombre_perro_var', '$last_id')";
echo $sql2;
if (!$mysqli->query($sql2)) {
    echo 'Error: ', $mysqli->error;
}
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

Please forgive this code, I'm new and learning.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be learning something that's deprecated, especially when just starting out.  Also, what error did you get?

Comment: you should be learning [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql

Comment: As the others said, you actually shouldn't be using it. I deleted my comment for that reason.

Comment: once you are using mysqli this should answer your question http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql_`

**Connecting with mysqli:**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database_name);
```

**Inserting into a table:**

```
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

**Retrieving last inserted id:**

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Comment: So how would one go about it when using PDO?

Comment: **connect:** `$connection = new pdo('mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database_name', $username, $password);` **Querying database:** `$connection->query($sql);` **last inserted id:** `$connection->lastInsertId;` eventually you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) though as they are safer and better to use

Answer (score 0):

```
**Database**

CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
) 



**Example (MySQLi Object-oriented)**
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    ***$last_id = $conn->insert_id;***
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

**Example (MySQLi Procedural)**
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    ***$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);***
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

**Example (PDO)**
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    ***$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();***
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A procedural solution (although it might be slightly wrong - I'm terrible at PHP)...

```
<?php
include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
INSERT INTO fecha (fecha) VALUES (NOW());
 ";

mysqli_query($db,$query);

$query = "
INSERT INTO perro (nombre_perro,id_fecha) VALUES (?,?);
";

$nombre_perro = 'rover';

$id_fecha = mysqli_insert_id($db);

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db,$query);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $nombre_perro,$id_fecha);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

?>
```

You might consider binding both queries into a transaction, so that in the event that the second query fails for some reason, then the first query fails too.